# How to add Pagination to Swiper carousel in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I use "swiper": "6.8.4" in React app and create carousel. Everything is working, except pagination - its not appearing on the page.
Do you see what I do in a wrong way?

[swiper pagination api docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination)

```
...
function Carousel() {
  return (
      <Swiper
        
        modules={[EffectFade, Keyboard, Pagination, Autoplay]}
        pagination={{
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          type: 'bullets',
        }}

        effect={'fade'}
        fadeEffect={{crossFade: true}}
        freeMode={true}
        autoplay={{
          delay: 2500,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        }}
        keyboard={{
          enabled: true,
          onlyInViewport: true,
          onPageUp: true,
        }}
        className="mySwiper"
        cssMode={true}
        loop={false}
        mousewheel={true}
        slidesPerView={1}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>0</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>1</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
  )
}

export default Carousel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share that we must be aware of how we import Swiper into our React apps.

In my case, I finally changed the Swiper version to "swiper": "8.1.4".
Then I imported it like:

```
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react/swiper-react'
```

and it started to work.

[Swiper NPM package is now a pure ESM package](https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide#node-es-modules). Which means it doesn't have CommonJS modules anymore (the ones with require() and module.exports syntax) and contains only native ES modules. If your bundler/tooling/environment doesn't support Node ES module, you should update it or stay on Swiper 6.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still want to use **Swiper 6**, import it this way:

```
// swiper bundle styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'

// swiper core styles
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'

// modules styles
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.min.css'
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css'

// swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

// swiper modules you want to use
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
```

Modules need to be installed using SwiperCore.use() method on Swiper class:

```
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination]);

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={"auto"}
        pagination={{
            clickable: true,
          }}
        navigation={true}
        className="mySwiper"
      > ...
```